# Sender e-mail address, for new order email to customer, is suddenly wrong

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, email-verification

I have an e-shop on WooCommerce version 4.1.1 and the past 2 days now it sends the new order email to customers from my personal administrator email, that belongs to another domain, instead of the orders@shopdomainhere.store

Before that, it was coming just fine with the information as shown in the screenshot that is in the WooCommerce setup.

 [image]

Any ideas?

Thanks!
Vassilis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the culprit. It was the Mailchimp plugin. After I changed the address it worked.